# How to load .TMX file in Cocos2d Android using cocos2d-android.jar

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, tile, tmx

This is my First question and I searched thoroughly in SO to find the solution of my problem. But I dint get it.
I am developing a demo game in Android using cocos2d-android.jar (Cococs2d not Cocos2d-x).
Following is my java code to load the TMX file:

```
public class GameLayer extends CCLayer {

    private CGSize _winSize;
    protected ArrayList<CCSprite> _targets;
    protected ArrayList<CCSprite> _projectiles;
    protected int _projectilesDestroyed;
    protected CCSprite _player;
    protected CCSprite _nextProjectile;
    protected CCTMXTiledMap _map;
    protected CCTMXLayer _background;
    protected CCTMXLayer _foreground;
    protected CCTMXLayer _meta;
    protected CCTMXObjectGroup _objects;
    protected HashMap<String, String> _spawnPoint;

    protected GameLayer() {
        super();
        _winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
        _targets = new ArrayList<CCSprite>();
        _projectiles = new ArrayList<CCSprite>();
        _projectilesDestroyed = 0;

        // Get TMX Map and associated layers/groups
        _map = CCTMXTiledMap.tiledMap("MyTiledMap.tmx"); // The app is crashing at this line
        _background = _map.layerNamed("Background");
        _foreground = _map.layerNamed("Foreground");
        _meta  = _map.layerNamed("Meta");
        _meta.setVisible(false);

        _objects = _map.objectGroupNamed("Objects");
        if(_objects == null){
            Log.e("BoxAway", "Tile map has no objects..");
        }

        // Add my background layer
        // TODO: Position layer in the correct spot.
//      addChild(_background);
        addChild(_map);

        _spawnPoint = _objects.objectNamed("SpawnPoint");

        _player = CCSprite.sprite("player.png");

        setPlayerPosition(CGPoint.ccp(100.0f, 100.0f));

        addChild(_player);
        setViewPointCentered(_player.getPosition());

        Context context = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();
        /*SoundEngine.sharedEngine().preloadEffect(context, R.raw.pew_pew_lei);
        SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context,
                R.raw.background_music_aac, true);*/

        this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);
        this.schedule("update");
    }

    public void setViewPointCentered(CGPoint pos) {
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;

        x = Math.max(pos.x, _winSize.width / 2);
        y = Math.max(pos.y, _winSize.height / 2);

        x = Math.min(x, (_map.getMapSize().width * _map.getTileSize().width)
                - _winSize.width / 2);
        y = Math.min(y, (_map.getMapSize().height * _map.getTileSize().height)
                - _winSize.height / 2);

        CGPoint actualPos = CGPoint.ccp(x, y);

        CGPoint centerOfView = CGPoint.ccp(_winSize.width / 2,
                _winSize.height / 2);
        CGPoint viewPoint = CGPoint.ccpSub(centerOfView, actualPos);

        _background.setPosition(viewPoint);
    }

    public static CCScene scene() {
        CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
        CCLayer layer = new GameLayer();

        scene.addChild(layer);

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;

    }

    void setPlayerPosition(CGPoint position) {
        _player.setPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event) {

        // Choose one of the touches to work with
        CGPoint touchLocation = CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY());
        touchLocation = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(touchLocation);
        touchLocation = this.convertToNodeSpace(touchLocation);

        CGPoint playerPosition = _player.getPosition();
        CGPoint diff = CGPoint.ccpSub(touchLocation, playerPosition);

        if (Math.abs(diff.x) > Math.abs(diff.y)) {
            if (diff.x > 0) {
                playerPosition.x += _map.getTileSize().width;
            } else {
                playerPosition.x -= _map.getTileSize().width;
            }
        } else {
            if (diff.y > 0) {
                playerPosition.y += _map.getTileSize().height;
            } else {
                playerPosition.y -= _map.getTileSize().height;
            }
        }

        if (playerPosition.x <= (_map.getMapSize().width * _map.getTileSize().width)
                && playerPosition.y <= (_map.getMapSize().height * _map
                        .getTileSize().height)
                && playerPosition.y >= 0
                && playerPosition.x >= 0) {
            setPlayerPosition(playerPosition);
        }

        setViewPointCentered(_player.getPosition());

        return true;

    }

    public void finishShoot() {
        addChild(_nextProjectile);
        _projectiles.add(_nextProjectile);
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
        ArrayList<CCSprite> projectilesToDelete = new ArrayList<CCSprite>();

        for (CCSprite projectile : _projectiles) {
            CGRect projectileRect = CGRect.make(projectile.getPosition().x
                    - (projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                    projectile.getPosition().y
                            - (projectile.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                    projectile.getContentSize().width,
                    projectile.getContentSize().height);

            ArrayList<CCSprite> targetsToDelete = new ArrayList<CCSprite>();
            for (CCSprite target : _targets) {
                CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x
                        - (target.getContentSize().width),
                        target.getPosition().y
                                - (target.getContentSize().height),
                        target.getContentSize().width,
                        target.getContentSize().height);

                if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect)) {
                    targetsToDelete.add(target);
                }
            }

            for (CCSprite target : targetsToDelete) {
                _targets.remove(target);
                removeChild(target, true);
            }

            if (targetsToDelete.size() > 0) {
                projectilesToDelete.add(projectile);
            }
        }

        /*for (CCSprite projectile : projectilesToDelete) {
            _projectiles.remove(projectile);
            removeChild(projectile, true);
            if (++_projectilesDestroyed > 30) {
                _projectilesDestroyed = 0;
                CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(
                        GameOverLayer.scene("You Win!"));
            }
        }*/
    }
```

Following is my "MyTiledMap.tmx" file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="50" height="20" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tmw_desert_spacing" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" spacing="1" margin="1">
  <image source="tmw_desert_spacing.png" width="265" height="199"/>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="49" name="meta_tiles" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" spacing="1" margin="1">
  <image source="meta_tiles.png" width="67" height="34"/>
     <tile id="0">
         <properties>
             <property name="Collidable" value="True"/>
         </properties>
     </tile>
     <tile id="1">
         <properties>
             <property name="Collectable" value="True"/>
         </properties>
     </tile>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Background" width="50" height="20">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJzjZ2Bg4B/Fo3gUj+JRPIpH8SgexaOYAOaC4oF2B739QYp6LjLMH6r+wCVPSJ8eheZgEyeklhb+UBrFo5gGGACGu0Ur
  </data>
 </layer>
 <objectgroup name="Objects" width="50" height="20">
  <object name="SpawnPoint" x="1578" y="519"/>
 </objectgroup>
 <layer name="Foreground" width="50" height="20">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJztzKERAAAIAkA3cf8t7SaCZ/qPwFEFAADwq8PsYru7ZJN+wqUBEIEBGA==
  </data>
 </layer>
 <layer name="Meta" width="50" height="20">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJzt0EsKACAIRVG3pPtfXJMGEYoKUQT3wJukfUwEAAAAyOnM77pzdPpV7v3T6zmievUec/ptqWfrnd69Fu2tvMs7m5BTGRCqJSw=
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

When I run the project, its crashing with the following Logcat stack trace:

```
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{application.pidex.src.boxaway/application.pidex.src.boxaway.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at java.nio.IntToByteBufferAdapter.get(IntToByteBufferAdapter.java:147)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at org.cocos2d.layers.CCTMXLayer.setupTiles(CCTMXLayer.java:310)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at org.cocos2d.layers.CCTMXTiledMap.parseLayer(CCTMXTiledMap.java:212)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at org.cocos2d.layers.CCTMXTiledMap.<init>(CCTMXTiledMap.java:143)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at org.cocos2d.layers.CCTMXTiledMap.tiledMap(CCTMXTiledMap.java:115)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at application.pidex.src.boxaway.GameLayer.<init>(GameLayer.java:44)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at application.pidex.src.boxaway.GameLayer.scene(GameLayer.java:101)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at application.pidex.src.boxaway.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:45)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
08-10 15:38:27.433: E/AndroidRuntime(500):  ... 11 more
```

Can somebody point me in right direction please?
Other source/links which shows loading and moving Tiled maps with cocos2d in Android are also welcomed..

Comment: I got success, in loading the Tiled map. But its not displaying properly. Below is the link which shows how the map is being loading in my emulator. Can anyone know the solution to resolve this??? [link] http://s21.postimg.org/he45kj5hj/device_2013_08_12_150646.png

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, get the latest version of the library from https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d.git, Either build it or look for a built jar.

It is an issue that was solved in https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/issues/detail?id=50
Cheers!
PZ